# How can I make last month name dynamic in title using Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to create a custom field in score card so the titles of the tables are dynamic.
I would like to make 3 of them:

- Current month > February
- -1 month > January
- -2 month > December

Below example of dashboard:
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/0a45e6ba-deba-41d1-b158-87b29c6990a2

I already have tried something like `Todate((),-1,MMMM)` but that did not work.

Below a image for extra information.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved using [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479) with the following [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

## 0) Scorecard Settings

The configuration that will be used for all three [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479):

**Data Tab**

- ***Aggregation***: [`MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583208) (either [`MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583208) or [`MIN`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583210) would result in the same value, thus selecting either [Aggregation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9320174) would be fine, in this case)
- ***Type***: Date & Time > Month

**Style Tab**

- ***Hide Metric Name***: Select (☑)

## 1) Current Month

The [`DATETIME_TRUNC`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9729685) function is used to get the [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736967) at a more granular level, in this case, by `MONTH`:

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)
```

## 2) Last Month

This uses `1) Current Month` as the base and wraps it with the [`DATETIME_SUB`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9699809) function, which subtracts `1` `MONTH` from the [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736967) `MONTH` value:

```
DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

## 3) -2 Months

Replaces `1` with `2` in the `INTERVAL 2 MONTH` section of the [`DATETIME_SUB`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9699809) function from `2) Last Month`:

```
DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ebbd4d81-2772-4ac6-b005-b44c875164d8) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12NBeQ2SVSWkdhz-CY-9r4wrN-x3PjH586b6RvQnm54I/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]